# Monitor linux users logins and logouts script

Tags: linux, session, authentication, terminal

My problem is I need to monitor all the users that have logged on or logged out in real time. I know there is `auth.log` file, but I don't have permissions to it. Is there any way of displaying only the usernames and login/logout time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use trace logged users with focus on running processes. Following scenario do it:

```
#!/bin/sh
mv current.log previous.log #Use two log file for compare users
ps aux | awk " {print $ 1}" |sort | uniq > current.log #Here unique users list
diff current.log previous.log | grep ">\|<" #comparring users lists
```

In result you can view next:

```
< avahi #logout user
> 123   #login user
> sfdfs #login user
```

Comment: I only need to know the if the user has logged on or logged out and if possible at what time.

Answer (score 2):

To see which users are currently logged in, there are traditionally the commands `who` and `w` on Unix systems.  Calling these is not restricted.  Due to privacy reasons normal users should not be allowed to see *when* which users logged on or off.

That is the reason why what you want to do cannot be achieved properly with what is available to you.  You will have to use workarounds each of which will have caveats.

The answer of Michael tries to achieve your goal by logging the list of current users (he's using `ps` but I would prefer `who` or `w` for this task).  If this is done regularly (each minute or each hour or so) then later you can scan your log file to find out when who appeared and disappeared.  I'd use it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

log() {
  line=$(who | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u)
  echo "$(date): " $line  # _NO_ quotes around $line!
}

while sleep 3600
do
  log >> user.log
done &  # do this in the background
```

Each hour this will log who is online into the file `user.log`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I've managed to make it work combining who command with diff and a loop. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Also, maybe the `last` command is what you can use.